# c++ preload a file into virtual memory?

Tags: c++, memory-mapped-files

I have a program that computes some statistics for a set of very large files.  While reading the file into ram my process is IO bound for ~30 seconds then my process is cpu bound for ~60 seconds as I analyze the buffer

```
for ( i=0; i<n; ++i )
{
    read_file_into_buffer(filename[i], buffer) // ~30 seconds
    analyze_buffer(buffer)                     // ~60 seconds
}
```

Is there anyway to request the os to start loading files into virtual memory for me before I go to read them into the buffer.  something similar to the following?

```
for ( i=0; i<n; ++i )
{
    read_file_into_buffer(filename[i], buffer)
    if (i<n-1)
        tell_os_i_will_want_to_read_this_soon(filename[i+1]);
    analyze_buffer(buffer)
}
```

Comment: Also, can this be solved with a helper thread?

Comment: Or... Just make 2nd thread, which loads next file in background.

Comment: Does the complete buffer have to be loaded before it's analyzed? Could you stream it a chunk at a time? ... the thinking being the OS might be nice enough to intelligently read ahead on the file (I know at least Windows does this).

Comment: I am using ubuntu and I do need to use the full buffer to do the computations.  I can't run a 2nd thread as I am running 4 of these in parallel already on 4 separate files on a 4 core box.